# I have a box turtle that has a very long beak, how can I shave it down without having to take him to the Vets office?

Tags: reptiles

My male turtle has a very long beak. It is very difficult for him to pick up his food to eat. I don't want to put him through the stress of going to a Vet's office.

What can I use to shave his beak down safely?

Comment: I suspect that the stress of an inexperienced dentist would be worse than the stress of a vet's visit.

Comment: Once upon a time I saw the "Emergency Vets" (Animal Planet show from the later 1990s) do this with a Dremel brand rotary tool.  I do not know what kind of bit was in the tool, but it looked like a filing bit.  Here's someone else doing something similar: http://www.doberdawn.com/doberdawn/dremel.html